# How can I play Guitar Hero 3 (PC) using PS3 guitar on Windows 8

Tags: controllers, windows-8, guitar-hero

I know that it was quite simple to set up and use Guitar Hero 3 guitar from PS3 when I was using Windows 7. Now, my new PC already has Windows 8. And, while my PS3 is long gone, I still kept the guitar, because I could use it with my PC game. For some reason tho, Windows 8 is not recognizing the device anymore.

How can I set up the controller on Windows 8?

Comment: Are you playing with it wired or through bluetooth? If wired, did you remember to re-install the libusb driver that PS3 controllers need? Not sure if that old driver still works on Windows 8 or not, but it's a start.

Comment: I did not need no such library. Google search suggests, that it is only usable by PS3 controller, not guitar. The PS3 guitars worked fine without them. I will try this when I get home, maybe it will help.